# Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors

Tags: web, joomla

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; POMO_Reader has a deprecated constructor in /public_html/administrator/components/com_uniterevolution2/inc_php/framework/pomo/streams.php on line 12

I tried renaming the class function with `class ();`.
I also tried changing the PHP version but nothing so far.

```
if ( !class_exists( 'POMO_Reader' ) ):
class POMO_Reader {

    var $endian = 'little';
    var $_post = '';

    function POMO_Reader() {
        $this->is_overloaded = ((ini_get("mbstring.func_overload") & 2) != 0) && function_exists('mb_substr');
        $this->_pos = 0;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't getting much attention here, you might try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your class and function uses the same name (`POMO_Reader`), so change the class name to somrthing different, such as `POMOReader` (without the `_`).

So your final code will look something like:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'POMOReader' ) ):
class POMOReader {

    var $endian = 'little';
    var $_post = '';

    function POMO_Reader() {
        $this->is_overloaded = ((ini_get("mbstring.func_overload") & 2) != 0) && function_exists('mb_substr');
        $this->_pos = 0;
    }
```